Can I add utm URL parameters to third party link tracking to improve the stats in Google Analytics?
I have these links that are built by a third party company, like this:
<a class="button" href="https://thirdparty.com/redirect/&utm_campaign=hosted" target="_blank"><img src="//imgix.net/media-lp/amazon-btn.jpg"></a>
So, that example link would take you to amazon. But the problem is that there is a department that wants to track the end retailer, but that link does not show that information. When we click that link and use a tool like Analytics debugger, there is no eretailer_exit or no other parameter like link_hostname or link_url identifying that the link is taking you to amazon.com.
Am I able to add a parameter in the link itself that would identify the end retailer?

This probably depend on the third party.  Are they sending this data to Google Analytics on your behalf?  Do they have any documentation?

I presume here that the department who wants the vendor is your department and not the vendor or third party department. When a third party needs data, they should indicate how they want you to track that.
For internal click tracking, you don't want to use utm parameters. You normally use utms to pass the data about the click context to the link destination. Misusing utms can actually be quite harming to the data integrity. It's able to quickly mess up channel attribution. You don't want that.
See there's an image in the <a> And the name of it indicates the vendor! Well then you could just parse that instead of populating the data-attributes or query params! Just grab the target's inner html and check if it contains amazon or whatever vendor and return the appropriate vendor name. A custom JS variable that looks something like: if (/amazon/i.test({{Click Element}}.innerHTML)) return "amazon"; and so on for all the vendors. {{Clicked Element}} is how GTM allows access to the target. Or maybe just get the {{Click Element}}.getAttribute("src") instead if the click actually lands on the image rather than the link from GTM's perspective. It's easy to see in the preview debugger in the Click Element variable value.
Then you use this CJS variable to populate a custom dimension of your choosing and you're all set.

No. Unless you connect Google Analytics to the database of redirects and their end URLs, GA has no way of determining what the end retailer is from the URL.
You could add a parameter manually into the redirect URL in the website code to track the end retailer (like &utm_retailer=amazon), but with just the information of the redirect URL by itself, there is no way of determining the end URL without resolving it.
